# Reading from Active Storage Attachment Before Save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I have users uploading JSON files as part of a model called `Preset`, very standard Active Storage stuff. One thing that's somewhat out of the ordinary (I suppose, given my inability to make it work) is that I'd like to grab data from the uploaded JSON file and use it to annotate the `Preset` record, like so:

```
class Preset < ApplicationRecord
    has_one_attached :hlx_file
    before_save :set_name

    def set_name
        file = JSON.parse(hlx_file.download)
        self.name = file['data']['name']
    end
end
```

When I call hlx_file.download I get `ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError: ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError`.

Comment: Is this on rails 6?  on rails 5.2 this worked, I'm facing the same problem on rails 6 where download or download_to methods seem to fail if the record is not yet saved. Looks related to this change: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33303

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rails 6 changed the moment of uploading the file to storage to during the actual save of the record.

This means that a before_save or validation cannot access the file the regular way.

If you need to access the newly uploaded file you can get a file reference like this:

```
record.attachment_changes['<attributename>'].attachable
```

This will be a tempfile of the to-be-attached file.

NOTE: The above is an undocumented internal api and subject to change (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37005)

Answer (score 0):

you use `before_save :set_name` which call the file before it actually being saved you can use `after_save` instead

1. try to use [url_for()](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html) funtion `file = JSON.parse(url_for(hlx_file))`
2. also dont forget to `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` at your model

Comment: I *want* to access the file `before_save` because I don't want to have to write to the database twice.